# why :e % doesn't work in Windows Vim

Tags: vim

From time to time I use a `:e %` command. This command simply says

> Edit current buffer

It worked on `Linux` and `Mac` machines, but recently I was forced to switch to a `Windows` machine and whenever I type `:e %` I get a list of environment variables. I do know that environment variables in `Windows` start with `%`. So how do I edit a current buffer in `Windows` in `Vim`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. It works perfectly fine for me on windows.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Hmm... That's interesting. [Here is what I'm getting](https://ibin.co/30qiLdNHy56V.png) when I type `e %`. Did I compile my `vim` incorrectly? Is there a flag that tells me how `e %` is used?

Comment: It looks you did autocompletion instead of hitting enter? Have you thought about just using `:e` which already edits the current file?

Comment: @FDinoff I use `:e %` to get a full path to the file name, then I delete the file name at the end and type a new file. I do have search engine plugin which allows me to search for files, but from time to time I have to access files which are not in search path of the plugin, which is where this command helps me.

Comment: @flashburn That is not obvious from your question... It sounds like you want `:e %:h/`, which removes the last part of the file path `:e %:h/` seems to support tab completion (on linux anyways)

Comment: @flashburn, pressing Tab after `:e %` reproduces that behaviour. Pressing Enter does not, and simply edits the current buffer on VIM 8.0 with patches 1-32 for Windows 64-bit, GUI version.

Answer (score 0):

```
  How do I edit the current file in vim?
```

Well, In most cases, the current file is opened in a buffer and is the main file you are editing. If you want to edit the current file, press `i` to get into insert mode and change, or use commands to delete,copy, paste and add characters, blocks, lines, paragraphs of text. 
In case if your current file is only readable, you can still edit it and save it with a new name by typing `:w newname`. 
If you are particular that you want to use `:e` (edit) command to edit the file, you can directly give `:e` to edit the current file(buffer). Most commands in vim accept an argument. So, `:e` also accepts a filename as an argument and edits that file. If you dont provide any filename, then it takes the current buffer.

Even though `:e` is enough to edit the current file, if you are still eager to edit the file with % symbol, then, type `:e` and then press Ctrl<\kbd>+R<\kbd> and then `%`. It inserts the current file's name in command line. You can now edit it.